# Updating only one row from a join table where there may be multiple identical rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this might get a little complicated, but I've tried to distill it as much as possible. Basically I have a table with 'items', a table with 'slots', a join table, 'slots_items' between the two because slots can have items, a 'history' table in case one item gets changed to another item, which then updates all the links in the 'slots_items' table, and a 'history_slots' table to indicate which slots were affected by an item change.

Now, I'm trying to find a way to "undo" a history change. If someone makes a history to change item A to item B, it's possible that slot 1 might already have item B, in which case you might get two entries in the join table that join item B and slot 1. That's fine (for me) because I can use some simple grouping to make sure item B only returns once.

However, if I want to undo a history change, I'm trying to find a way to say "update only the first instance in 'slots_items' for each slot where the history_slots entry matches the slot and the history.oldItem matches the item". I don't want to update *both* instances of slot 1 <-> item B because there actually *was* an item B on that slot originally. So I want to go from two entries of slot 1 <-> item B back to slot 1 <-> item A and slot 1 <-> item B.

Unfortunately I can't (seem to) simply do an "UPDATE TOP(1) ..." because there might be more than one slot that was affected by an item history change. So if there was a slot 2 that also had an item A that was updated to item B, I want to also revert that slots_items entry at the same time.

To put it in SQL...

```
DECLARE @items TABLE(
    id VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO @items VALUES('A'),('B'),('C');

DECLARE @slots TABLE(
    id INT
);
INSERT INTO @slots VALUES(1),(2),(3);

DECLARE @slots_items TABLE(
    fk_slots INT,
    fk_items VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO @slots_items VALUES(1,'B'),(1,'B'),(2,'C'),(2,'B'),(2,'C');

DECLARE @history TABLE(
    id INT,
    fk_oldItem VARCHAR,
    fk_newItem VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO @history VALUES(100,'A','B');

DECLARE @history_slots TABLE(
    fk_history INT,
    fk_slots INT
);
INSERT INTO @history_slots VALUES(100,1),(100,2);
```

So in this dataset (after an item change), slot 1 will have items B, B, C and slot 2 will have items B, C.

I want to be able to undo this (do an update) such that it will read that slot 1 has items A, B, C and slot 2 has items A, C. Any ideas/help?  **Edit to attempt clarification:** I want update all entries in @slots_items to set fk_items from B to A, but ONLY once per slot as the same slot/item combo may occur more than once.

I've thought of the possibility of instead of the history table pointing to the slots that were affected instead pointing to the join table entries that were affected, but then that would require adding a primary key to a join table. Not overly fond of the idea, but may do it if absolutely necessary. I'd much rather find a solution where I don't have to add a primary key to a join table though if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `row_number()` for this purpose.  You need some sort of column that specifies the ordering, so let me assume a `creationdate` column.  I find the logic and data very hard to follow.  But, to change the most recent record in `@history_slots` to `'A'`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select hs.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by creationdate desc) as seqnum
      from history_slots hs
     )
update todupdate
    set fk_oldItem = 'A'
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Not quite... I'm trying to update slots_items, so I tried to modify your query to the following... `WITH cte AS (SELECT si.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY h.id ORDER BY h.changeDate) AS seqnum FROM @history h INNER JOIN @history_slots hs ON h.id = hs.fk_history INNER JOIN @slots_items si ON hs.fk_slots = si.fk_slots) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE fk_items = 'B' AND seqnum = 1;` and that only gives me the first result, but I need all the results where fk_items = 'B', but only one instance per slot.